# Get the number of records from a database using sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, unit-testing

I am creating a test that will return the number of records in a table after I insert one record into it.  The table in the database is initially empty so the count should return 1.  This is the code I have written so far:

```
[TestMethod]
public void InsertBookIntoDb() {
    Database db = new Database();
    db.insertBooks("A", "C", "T");

    OleDbCommand countCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book", db.DbConnection);
    int count = countCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Assert.AreEqual(1, count);
}
```

My db.insertBooks() method works correctly because I can manually open up the database and see that there is a new record.  After running this test, the count value is always 0 no matter how many records I insert into the database.  Is there a better way to get the total number of records?

Answer (score 8):

You need [OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Use the ExecuteScalar method to retrieve a single value, for example,
>   an aggregate value, from a data source.

```
 int count = (int) countCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: I also had to use Thread.Sleep(1000) to get it to execute correctly

Comment: @user2246631, not really sure why you need that, Your code doesn't seem to execute it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `ExecuteNonQuery` which is typically used for SQL statements without results (e.g., UPDATE, INSERT, etc.).

we use ExecuteScalar typically when our query returns a single value.
So just replace the `ExecuteNonQuery' with the`ExecuteScalar'. It will work correctly.

```
    [TestMethod]
public void InsertBookIntoDb() {
    Database db = new Database();
    db.insertBooks("A", "C", "T");

    OleDbCommand countCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book", db.DbConnection);
    int count = (int) countCommand.ExecuteScalar();

    Assert.AreEqual(1, count);
}
```

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` returns `object`, you need to cast/convert it to `int`, otherwise you will get an error